# How are binlogs updated for MySQL temporary tables?

Tags: mysql, logs

1. If I use `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`, can I write and update this MySQL table and know that none of it will be stored to the binlogs?
2. If I use data from the temp table to write to a non-temp table, is the
   part-of-the-statement-that-reads-from-temp-table
   simply substituted with plain values, or is there something else that happens in the binlog to indicate the data source?

   I ask this because normally when reading from another table, the binlog shows the whole statement, meaning it normally does not substitute the plain values.

Comment: I think that this should be tagged with either `statement-logs` or `binlogs`. I cannot create these tags myself.

Answer (score 3):

Statements like `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` will land in the binary logs. This has plaugued me for years when troubleshooting. Here is why:

In MySQL Replication, if you create a temp table, it will remain in existence as long as the SQL thread is in session. I have had dozens of instances where someone would schedule a nightly backup which included `STOP SLAVE;` before the mysqldump and `START SLAVE;` afterwards. When you run `STOP SLAVE;`, it terminates both the IO thread and the SQL thread for Replication. When the SQL thread dies, all tables created with `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` are dropped immediately. When you try to run `START SLAVE;`, MySQL Replication breaks instantly, stating that the table it was INSERTing into or SELECTing from does not exist. How did I find the table? I would have to run [**mysqlbinlog**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) against the master's binary logs to locate the position that the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` was issued.

So, to answer both questions, all you have to do is this:

Any INSERT into a temp table should like like this:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
INSERT INTO tmptable ... ;
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;
```

Any UPDATE of a temp table should like like this:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
UPDATE tmptable SET ... ;
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;
```

Any INSERT into a real table using data from a temp table should like like this:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;
INSERT INTO realtable SELECT ... FROM tmptable ... ;
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;
```

#### **UPDATE 2012-03-19 17:06 EDT**

I read your comment

**Question 1 from your comments : What happens if two threads both create temp tables of the same name?** Do the statements fall into the binlogs and conflict?

**Answer** : Each temp table of identical names (even identical schemas) are unique to the the DB Connection that opened it. Therefore, no conflict whatsoever. In fact, since replication is single-threaded along the SQL thread, all SQL statements with temp tables of identical names are processed in a serialized manner, i.e., like a FIFO queue.

**Question 2 from your comments : Wouldn't this cause the changes to realtable to not be reflected in the binlogs?**

**Answer** : You are correct. Therefore, since you want the changes to the realtable  replicated to the Slave, you will not need `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0;`

Comment: **1.** What happens if two threads both create temp tables of the same name? Do the statements fall into the binlogs and conflict? **2.** `SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0; INSERT INTO realtable SELECT ... FROM tmptable ... ; SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;` Wouldn't this cause the changes to `realtable` to not be reflected in the binlogs?