# Is it bad to create many mysql temporary tables simultaneously?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, memory, temporary-tables

I need to make heavy statistical analysis to deliver some data to users. Currently, I catch the data from mysql and process them via `PHP` arrays. However, mysql temporary tables are quite better (extremely more efficient and faster than PHP arrays; obviously due to their mechanism).

My tentative solution is to form a temporary table upon each request (i.e. connection) to import and process the data. However, I am not sure if there is a drawback for creating many temporary tables simultaneously?

Can this make problem for the mysql server? Or I can use it as an alternative to PHP arrays in numerous simultaneous requests?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to prevent making temp tables as much as possible : [Prevent copying to temp table (sql)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/4037/prevent-copying-to-temp-table-sql/4044#4044)

They do not work well in MySQL Replication : [How are binlogs updated for MySQL temporary tables?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15260/how-are-binlogs-updated-for-mysql-temporary-tables/15263#15263)

Since temp tables are a fact of life in the DB world, you may have to make some unorthodox changes to accommodate their existence.

Normally, mysqld has the habit of placing tmp tables in `/tmp` or wherever [tmpdir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) is configured. That's usually on some poor unsuspecting disk.

An interesting alternative would be to setup a RAM disk and reconfigure [tmpdir](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) to use it

STEP 01 : Create a Mount Point for a RAM Disk

```
mkdir /var/tmpfs
```

STEP 02 : Add the RAM disk to /etc/fstab (16GB)

```
echo "none   /var/tmpfs              tmpfs   defaults,size=16g        1 2" >> /etc/fstab
```

STEP 03 : Add this line to /etc/my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
tmpdir=/var/tmpfs
```

STEP 04 : Enable the RAM Disk

You can do one of the following:

1. Just reboot the DB Server
2. `mount -t tmpfs -o size=16g none /var/tmpfs`

Before you do this, make sure you have enough RAM

Give it a Try !!!

Comment: _Implicit_ temp tables have no impact on replication, whether SBR or RBR.  _Explicit_ temp tables send all the DDLs across the wire.

Answer (score 4):

"Many mysql temporary tables" -- The potential issues:

- table_open_cache (and other tunables) -- You could (but are not likely to) hit some limit
- Ram bloat -- You could (but are not likely to) use more ram.  If this leads to swapping, that is really bad.

I would not worry about "many" unless you really have hundreds of temp tables at once.

How many threads (SHOW PROCESSLIST; ignore 'Sleep') are running at once?  Even a busy system rarely has more than 10 at once.

For *implicit* temp tables, let's see the SELECTs that are causing them; it may be possible to redesign the queries to avoid the temp tables.

I don't like using a ram-disk -- it takes RAM away from other caching possibilities, and runs the risk of hitting a hard limit (the disk size).