# MariaDB: Created_tmp_disk_tables high after start

Tags: mysql, mariadb

today i looked in the status of my MySQL server which is based on MariaDB and i noticed that 
Created_tmp_disk_tables is very high (over 168k). I think this is the reason for my high I/O usage. I try to optimize this by increasing tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size and some other config parameters.

Now i restarted the server and took a look at the status variables:

Created_tmp_disk_tables 12
Created_tmp_tables      82

The server is running for 20 seconds, but why it has created 12 tmp tables on the hdd? I set max_heap_table_size  and tmp_table_size to 256MB so it's not possible that this is full after 20 seconds.

After 5 Minutes the Status looks like this:

Created_tmp_disk_tables 40
Created tmp tables 3300

The difference is not as big as it was before increasing the RAM. But i can't understand why tmp tables are created on the hdd when enough RAM is avaliable. I think this is not good because it slow down the querys and create high I/O usage. My server also have enough RAM, so that i want to avoid this and make MariaDB to create all tmp tables in the RAM.

I use MariaDB on Debian 7.3

Comment: 1) Are you using Linux, 2) How much RAM on your DB Server ???

Comment: I use Debian 7.3 and mysqltuner tell me that 2.9GB of 16GB are assigned to MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

You may have other limiting factors involved. Here are some suggestions:

## Additional Buffers

The per-connections buffers you may need to increase includes

- [join_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_join_buffer_size)
- [sort_buffer_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_sort_buffer_size)

Queries will demand temp table based on join and sort operations. These may need to be increased.

## Improve Queries

Queries that need to do joins and sorts can be reduced if queries had proper indexing. I would suggest that you profile all your queries using [pt-query-digest](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-query-digest.html) and create whatever indexes that table need to reduce the incidence of temp table creation.

## Create a RAM Disk

You should map a chunk of your RAM to be a dedicated RAM disk. Then configure [**tmpdir**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_tmpdir) to point to it. See my post [Is it bad to create many mysql temporary tables simultaneously?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29636/is-it-bad-to-create-many-mysql-temporary-tables-simultaneously/29638#29638) on how to set one up.

Comment: Thanks, i'll let my server running and then look at Sort_merge_passes to find out if increasing is necessary. A RAM Disc sounds good. But after ~30min i've 163 tables which are created in 6 tmp files from a total amount of 36.2k tmp tables. I know 30min are to short to find this out. But if this value isn't increasing rapidly, do you think a RAM disc for them is still a good idea when only a few querys are affected?

Comment: A RAM disk for tmpdir has two drawbacks:  (1) it takes RAM away from other caches, thereby slowing down everything, and (2) if you need more space than was allocated, things crash instead of simply slow down.