# Write-lock a whole table during transaction

Tags: mysql, replication, innodb, transaction, locking

I need to perform a delicate operation to my table in which I will solely `insert`, `delete` and `select` upon all of my rows and no God may interfere with the table during this operation: the table will be in an inconsistent state and any concurrent MySQL session shall not be allowed to modify it until `commit`-ed.

The use of `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE | LOCK IN SHARE MODE` is not suitable because, while it may potentially be [used to lock all the rows in the table](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-locking-reads.html#SEE%20FIRST%20USER%20COMMENT%20BY%20Viktor%20S%C3%B6derqvist), it won't prevent the insertion of further rows by a concurrent session. Basically, I need to `LOCK TABLES my_table WRITE` within the body of a transaction.

The table contains about 20,000 rows and a master-slave, mixed-format replication is in place over a slow connection so, for any workaround, I'd prefer to avoid using temporary tables which may [faint the slave](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15260/how-are-binlogs-updated-for-mysql-temporary-tables/15263#15263), and the amount of data dumped into the binlog should ideally be minimized.

The engine is InnoDB on MySQL 5.6, for both master and slave.

Answer (score 0):

The Slave should be irrelevant, unless you are using (misusing) some form of parallel execution on the Slave.

Try other `transaction_isolation_modes`.

`GET_LOCK()/RELEASE_LOCK()` may provide a sufficient "lock"; but *all* writers to that table(s) would need to use it.

Do not turn on auto-reconnect in your connection.  An network glitch will mess with both the transaction and `GET_LOCK`.